# Does the reduction of the pole order to compute the Poincare residue work?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, cohomology

I am trying to understand the Poincare residue and referring to [On Computing Picard-Fuchs Equations](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Ecschnell/pdf/notes/picardfuchs.pdf), which is cited by Wikipedia's page on the Poincare residue.
On pp. 5--6, he gives a way to compute the Poincare residue of a rational $n$-form $\omega$ (which is $(n,0)$-form) on $\mathbb{P}^n$ as follows:

(A) Let $w=0$ be a local equation for the pole locus. Write $\omega=\frac{dw\wedge \rho}{\omega^k}$ for some number $k\geq1$.

(B) If $k\geq2$, lower the order of the pole by
\begin{align}
\frac{dw\wedge\rho}{w^k}=\frac{1}{k-1}\left(\frac{d\rho}{w^{k-1}}-d\left(\frac{\rho}{w^{k-1}}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{k-1}\frac{d\rho}{w^{k-1}}\quad \text{mod exact forms}.
\end{align}

(C) By glueing (B) using a partition of unity, obtain a globally defined form with a pole of smaller order.
This form may not be rational anymore, because the partitions of unity are not, but **it can still be written as in (A)**.

(D) When a pole of order one is reached, the Poincare residue is calculated by $\mathrm{Res}(\alpha\wedge\frac{dw}{w}+\beta)=\alpha|_\text{pole locus}$.

I am in trouble with the bold font part above. After we perform (A)--(C) one time, we obtain (rational $(n,0)$-form)$\times$(partition of unity), from which we can factor out $dw$ and write it as in (A), indeed. However, if we perform (A)--(C) one more time, then we can no longer say that we obtain a $(n,0)$-form, because the partition of unity is not holomorphic but just smooth. How can we factor out $dw$ from this not necessarily $(n,0)$-form and write it as in (A) again?

Because I am not from the background of mathematics, excuse me if I'm asking a dumb question. Any comments are helpful.